# Discord bot not on members list but online

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

I'm trying to start my first discord bot. Installed NodeJS on my PC, started app in discord dev tools, make it bot, got token, selected priviliges, added bot to my server. Actually another bot i already have even sent welcome message saying my new bot joined the server. When i start it using command "node main.js" it says it went online, doesn't give any errors, however my bot isn't showing in members list (neither offline nor online) and it doesn't react to messages with its prefix. Here's my main.js code:

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '=';

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if (command === 'status') {
        console.log(command);
        message.channel.send('Bot dziala poprawnie.');
    }
} );

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('GuruBot online');
});

client.login('my_token_is_here');```
````

Answer (score 0):

The bot probably doesn't have access to the text channel. Check the bot's permissions on your server, and check the invite link that you're using to make sure that the bot can view channels and incoming messages.

[image: view channels]
[image: send messages]

*I'm very late to the question, but hopefully this will help anyone who is searching for this issue.*